# Normal subgroup of set of all affine transformations in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, normal-subgroups

Let $\mathcal A(\mathbb R^2)$ be the set of all affine transformations of $\mathbb R^2.$ Let $\text {GL}(\mathbb R^2) = \{T_{M} \mid M\in \text {GL}_2(\mathbb R)\} $ be the set of all bijective linear transformations
where $T_M := T_{M,\boldsymbol{0}}$.

Is $\text {GL}(\mathbb R^2)$ a normal subgroup of $\mathcal A(\mathbb R^2)$ ?

My working:

$$\begin{align}
\text{GL}(\mathbb R^2) \text { is a normal subgroup of } \mathcal {A}(\mathbb R^2)
&\iff \alpha k\alpha^{-1} \in \text{GL}(\mathbb R^2) \text { for all } \alpha \in \mathcal {A}(\mathbb R^2) \text { where } k \in \text {GL}(\mathbb R^2).\\
&\iff \alpha T_{M}\big(T_{A^{-1},-A^{-1}\mathbf b}(\mathbf x)\big) \in \text {GL}(\mathbb R^2)\\
  &\iff \alpha(MA^{-1}\mathbf x-MA^{-1}\mathbf b) \in \text {GL}(\mathbb R^2)\\
  &\iff A(MA^{-1}\mathbf x-MA^{-1}\mathbf b) +\mathbf b  \in \text {GL}(\mathbb R^2)\\
  &\iff AMA^{-1}\mathbf x-(AMA^{-1}-I_{2})\mathbf b \in \text {GL}(\mathbb R^2)\\
  &\iff AMA^{-1} = I_{2}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Use `$$\begin{align} A &\iff B\\ &\iff C.\end{align}$$` for $$\begin{align} A &\iff B\\ &\iff C.\end{align}$$

Comment: Presumably the affine transformations in $\mathcal{A}(\Bbb{R}^2)$ are also assumed to be bijections?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you meant by the calculation you have there, but the fact is that $\text{GL}(V)$ is not a normal subgroup in $\mathcal{A}(V)$ for any finite-dimensional vector space $V$.

The reason this happens has all to do with the way $\text{GL}(V)$ and $\mathcal{A}(V)$ act on $V$ - in general, a good way to think about any group is to study the actions it has on different sets: in this particular case, there is a natural way to define the action of $\mathcal{A}(V)$ on $V$; namely $T_{M,v}(x)=Mx+v$.

The best way in my opinion to interpret conjugation in groups is by considering what happens to this action once we apply a transformation to the set the group is acting on.

For example, for every $v\in V$, consider the subgroup (called the stabiliser) $\mathcal{A}(V)_v=\{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}(V)\mid \alpha(v)=v\}\leq \mathcal{A}(V)$ of elements that fix $v$ via this action. Well, if we apply some $\beta\in\mathcal{A}(V)$ to $v$ and then calculate the stabiliser you can immediatly see what happens: $$
\mathcal{A}(V)_{\beta(v)}=\{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}(V)\mid\alpha(\beta(v))=\beta(v)\}=\{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}(V)\mid \beta^{-1}\alpha\beta(v)=v\}=\beta\mathcal{A}(V)_v\beta^{-1}
$$ we get the conjugate subgroup of the stabiliser (this is obviously valid in general).

In this particular example, we have that $0$ is (by definition) fixed by every linear transformation, namely $\text{GL}(V)\leq \mathcal{A}(V)_0$. Thus if we apply, for example, a translation $T_{0,v}$ for some non zero vector $v$, we get $$
\mathcal{A}(V)_{T_{0,v}(0)}=\mathcal{A}(V)_v=T_{0,v}\mathcal{A}(V)_0T_{0,-v}
$$ Which means $\text{GL}(V)$ **can not** be a normal subgroup, because if it were then $T_{0,v}\text{GL}(V)T_{0,-v}=\text{GL}(V)$ and hence $\text{GL}(V)$ would be a subgroup of $\mathcal{A}(V)_v$ where $v$ is non zero, which is clearly not the case: there are obvsiouly linear transformations which don't fix $v$ for any non zero $v$.

I'm aware my answer was a bit overload for this exercise, but I think this route was a bit more instructive that doing the mindless calculations :)

Comment: I'm just using the fact that to prove a subgroup $K \leq G$  is normal, it is enough to show that $gKg^{-1} \subseteq K \,\, \forall g \in G.$